# scroll down a div only if it has scrolled above the viewport

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a div and an anchor tag.

```
<div id="scrollDownifAboveScreen">Show all contents of this Div</div>
```

Anchor tag:

```
<a onclick="getFreshcontent();scrolltoDiv();">Refresh</a>
```

In a case, where user refreshed and the content of div was big, that user had to scroll down to read it. When he clicks Refresh again, I need to scroll down to the top of the div. But if the top of the div is still visible, then no scroll should happen. How can I do this?

I used this method:

```
function scrolltoDiv(){

       var position = $('#scrollDownifAboveScreen')[0].scrollTop;
       alert(position);
       if(position<230)
       {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#scrollDownifAboveScreen').offset().top-80 }, 'slow');
       }    

 }
```

But the alert always gives me Zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a onclick="getFreshcontent();" href="#scrollDownifAboveScreen">Refresh</a>
```

Have you tried like this?

Comment: I did know that. But if the top of the div is already visible, I dont want to scroll. Only if the top of div was scrolled above teh view port of screen, then it should scroll down.